# Prepare for multi language capability. Have I missed a trick?

Tags: c#, asp.net

My asp.net web app is currently being developed and I want to handle any language input by the user. This input will then be displayed to other users on the site.

So far I have done the following:

1. Put this is the head - meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"
2. Saved inputs in NVARCHAR fields

Do I need to do anything else? Do I need any other meta tags (content-language, etc)?

Answer (score 1):

Also think of a way to localize your UI, either via resources or with an appropriate support in your database. If the users are expected to generate non-English content, they will definitely appreciate seeing UI in their native language.

Comment: Good point. That's the next stage once this issue is complete.

Answer (score 1):

You should remember not to make assumptions that are not valid in general.

A fairly common assumption that is wrong is that `(str.ToUpper().ToLower() == str)` for any `string str`. A more subtle assumption is that the concept of "upper" and "lower" case even makes sense for any given language.

Another frequent problematic assumption is that a single `char` in the input is always an actual character from user's perspective. This is wrong - even setting things such as surrogate pairs aside, there are also combining characters. You either have to normalize your strings (and even that isn't 100% foolproof), or just avoid dealing with individual `char`s.

If you want to deal with more than just plain text input displayed verbatim - i.e. full, proper localization - you'll also have to handle number, date, currency etc formats correctly; and, for example, do not assume that decimal separator is a dot.

My best general advice would be to just go and read [Michael Kaplan's blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/michkap), Microsoft's local guru on localization and related issues. Look for categories (tags) such as "Collation/Casing", "Encoding/Codepages" and "Int'l Programming". There's a *lot* of stuff there, and most of it is either directly relevant to your question, or interesting, or both. If, after reading a couple of his blog posts, you start thinking that maybe hiring a localization expert just to point out potential non-obvious problems in that area is a good idea, then you're probably right :)

Answer (score 0):

- Whenever you use String.Format append client's culture spec. Using FxCop allows to explore these places.
- Exclude string constants from .cs code
- Place images (that can contain culture specific text) into skin files or resources.

Answer (score 0):

The browsers determine the charset in the following order:

1. Content-Type http header (value example: "text/html; charset=utf-8")
2. XML declaration
3. meta attribute

You should check that the web server does not send conflicting content type information in headers.

Make sure you save the files in UTF-8.